# How do I get setSelectionSymbol to work on Polygon layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to create a zoom-multiple query that will:

1. Select multiple features in a layer
2. Highlight them
3. Buffer an additional x feet around that selection extent

I just can't get `setSelectionSymbol` to work on this layer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Buffer in 2D and 3D - 4.1</title>

  <style>
    html,
    body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    }

.viewDivBase {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 700px;
    width: 700px;
}

    #viewDiv2d {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    }



.title {
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/mPower.Integrator/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/mPower.Integrator/libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



  <script>
    require([
        'dojo/_base/lang',
        'dojo/promise/all',
        'dojo/topic',
        'dojo/on',
        "esri/map",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/graphic",
        "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
        'esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol',
        'esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol',
        'esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol',
        "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
        'esri/graphicsUtils',
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/geometry/Polyline",
        "esri/geometry/Polygon",
        'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
        "esri/geometry/Extent",
        'esri/Color',
        'esri/tasks/query',
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ],
      function(
        lang,
        all,
        topic,
        on,
        Map,
        GraphicsLayer,
        Graphic,
        SimpleRenderer,        
        SimpleMarkerSymbol,
        SimpleLineSymbol,
        SimpleFillSymbol,
        geometryEngine,
        graphicsUtils,
        Point,
        Polyline,
        Polygon,
        FeatureLayer,
        Extent,
        Color,
        Query
      ) {
          'use strict';
          var selectionfeaturelayer;
          var promises = [];
          var map = new Map("viewDiv2d",{
              basemap: "topo",
              fitExtent: true,
              extent: new Extent({xmin:-85.8132362723161,ymin:38.1612613907511,xmax:-85.6422584745839,ymax:38.2706997066712,spatialReference:{wkid:4326}})
          });
          var polySym = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,new Color([255,0,0]), 2),new Color([255,255,0,0.25]));
          var bufferLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
              id: 'bufferGraphicsLayer',
              title: 'BufferGraphics',
              renderer: new SimpleRenderer({
                  symbol: polySym
              })
          });
          var featurelayerurl = "https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Louisville/LOJIC_LandRecords_Louisville/MapServer/0";
          var featurelayerparcel = new FeatureLayer(featurelayerurl,{outFields: "*"});
          featurelayerparcel.id = "PARCEL";
          featurelayerurl = "https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Louisville/LOJIC_PublicSafety_Louisville/MapServer/1";
          var featurelayerfire = new FeatureLayer(featurelayerurl,{outFields: "*"});    
          featurelayerfire.id = "FIRE";
          featurelayerurl = "https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Louisville/LOJIC_LandRecords_Louisville/MapServer/0";
          selectionfeaturelayer = new FeatureLayer(featurelayerurl, {outFields: "*", refreshInterval: 1});
          selectionfeaturelayer.id = "MYSELECTIONLAYER";
          var nullSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(5);
          var selectionSymbolx = new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([255,120,120,0.75]));
          selectionSymbolx.setOutline(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2));
          selectionfeaturelayer.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbolx);
          //selectionfeaturelayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleFillSymbol()));
          map.addLayers([bufferLayer, featurelayerparcel,featurelayerfire,selectionfeaturelayer]);
          var selectionsymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE,30,
              new SimpleLineSymbol(
                SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                new Color([255,0,0]),
                1
            ),
            new Color([0,0,255])
          );
          var selectQuery = new Query();
          selectQuery.returnGeometry = true;
          selectQuery.outFields = '*';
          selectQuery.where = "OBJECTID IN (5)";
          var geometries = [];
          promises.push(selectionfeaturelayer.selectFeatures(selectQuery, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW));
          all(promises).then(function (results) {
              var selectionSymbolx = new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([255,120,120,0.75]));
              selectionSymbolx.setOutline(new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2));
              selectionfeaturelayer.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbolx);
              var featureset = [];
              results.forEach(function (result) {
                  featureset.push(result);
              });
              var features = featureset.reduce(function (a, b) {
                  return a.concat(b);
              }, []);
              features.map(function (item) {
                  geometries.push(item.geometry);
              });
              var gfx = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(features);
              var extents = gfx.getExtent();
              var selectionPolygon = Polygon.fromExtent(extents);
              var buffered;
              try {
                  buffered = geometryEngine.geodesicBuffer(selectionPolygon, 100, "9002");
              }
              catch (e) {
                  try{
                      buffered = geometryEngine.buffer(selectionPolygon, 100, "9002");
                  }
                  catch (e) {
                      buffered = extents;
                  }
              }
              var graphic = new Graphic(buffered, polySym);
              bufferLayer.add(graphic);
              //THE ONLY WORKAROUND COULD BE ALLOT OF OBJECTS
              //geometries.forEach(function(geometry){
              //graphic = new Graphic(geometry, polySym);
              //bufferLayer.add(graphic);
              //});
              map.setExtent(buffered.getExtent(), false);
          }
          );
          return;
      });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="viewDivBase" id="viewDiv2d">
  <div class="title" style="right: 49.9%;">MapView</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the layer that you are selecting features from has a really restrictive scale dependency set.

from the [metadata](https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Louisville/LOJIC_LandRecords_Louisville/MapServer?f=pjson):

> Min. Scale: 6160.84032885541,

this means that *nothing* is going to be displayed unless you modify the property in your code or zoom in farther prior to executing your selection.

```
featureLayer.setMinScale(0);
```

live working sample:
http://jsbin.com/fufatog/edit?html,output

endnote: you've shared a whole bunch of code that distracts from your question regarding getting `setSelectionSymbol()` to function as you'd expect. next time it'd be a good idea to whittle down your repro case before posting.